# Separating One Column into Two Columns with Multiple Symbols

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that contains the `CustomerPO` and `CustShippingOrder` numbers combined and separated by a `-`:

```
PO
123456-7-89101112
```

I need the columns to be broken up like this:

```
Customer PO          CustShippingOrder
--------------------------------------
1234567              89101112
```

The 7 needs to be apart of the `Customer PO` column, I'm able to separate the columns but whenever I do, the `-` in the `-7-` stay.

This is the current code I have

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',PO)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(PO,1,CHARINDEX('-',PO)-1) 
ELSE PO END PO, 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',PO)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(PO,CHARINDEX('-',PO)+1,len(PO)) ELSE NULL END AS [Customer PO]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What code do you already have to separate them?  It should only take a minor tweak if you can provide your existing code.

Comment: SELECT
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',PO)>0
   THEN SUBSTRING(PO,1,CHARINDEX('-',PO)-1)
   ELSE PO END PO,
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',PO)>0
      THEN SUBSTRING(PO,CHARINDEX('-',PO)+1,len(PO))
   ELSE NULL END AS [Customer PO]

Comment: [edit] any clarifications into your question

Comment: Halfway there. Charindex accepts 3rd argument, starting position... Set it to 1+ position of first `-` to get the second hyphen. Btw, is the length of string/position of hyphens fixed?

Comment: Yes the length of string/position of hyphens is fixed

Answer (score 2):

`parsename()` seems like a good fit here

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (somecol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
 ('123456-7-89101112')

 Select A.SomeCol
       ,NewVal1 = parsename(NewStr,3)+parsename(NewStr,2)
       ,NewVal2 = parsename(NewStr,1)
  From  @YourTable A
  Cross Apply ( values ( replace(SomeCol,'-','.') ) )B(NewStr)
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol             NewVal1     NewVal2
123456-7-89101112   1234567     89101112
```